# Problem in starting Android Emulator from Eclipse

Tags: android, android-emulator

When i upgrade my sdk file and create AVD,AVD is successfully created but when i try to launch the AVD it comes with the error saying

> invalid command-line parameter: API.
>   Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
>   please use -help for more information

How can i recover from this! 
Please help me... Thanks in Advance!

Comment: and capture screen short

Comment: i'm unable to attach the screen shot image since my reputation is low ... Sorry!

Comment: ok delete avd and create again

Comment: now i fixed it by changing the location of Android SDK folder Thanks for your guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the space between Program Files. I guess your SDK is placed there. So you can fix that with changin it's destination. Try to place it in other directory,where you don't have space in it's name. That should fix the problem. If it's not please provide some more information about your problem.